# Can Two Contracts Import Each Other?

Tags: solidity, import

I have two contracts with variables and functions that each should need to reference/call. I would prefer to separate the contracts, as different user groups would be accessing each. Can two contracts import each other? Or is there an order of operations -so to speak- wherein only one contract can be dependent on another?

Comment: As far as I understand there can't be circular imports.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can compile two contracts that call each other.  For example,

```
contract InterfaceOfA {
        function f(uint) returns (uint);
}

contract InterfaceOfB {
        function g(bool) returns (bool);
}

contract A is InterfaceOfA {
        InterfaceOfB b;
        function f(uint _input) returns (uint) {
                b.g(true);
                return 3;
        }
}

contract B is InterfaceOfB {
        InterfaceOfA a;
        function g(bool _input) returns (bool) {
                a.f(0);
                return false;
        }
}
```

Comment: Functionally, is there any difference if the two contracts modify each other in the same .sol file vs. importing and modifying each other from separate .sol files?