# How this snippet is linking contracts? How each contract finds the other

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, contract-invocation, interfaces

I'm trying to understand how can two contracts be deployed and interact with each other, given that I don't have their addresses before deployment. I ended in [this question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/10037/68459) and I don't understand the answer.

```
contract InterfaceOfA {
        function f(uint) returns (uint);
}

contract InterfaceOfB {
        function g(bool) returns (bool);
}

contract A is InterfaceOfA {
        InterfaceOfB b;
        function f(uint _input) returns (uint) {
                b.g(true);
                return 3;
        }
}

contract B is InterfaceOfB {
        InterfaceOfA a;
        function g(bool _input) returns (bool) {
                a.f(0);
                return false;
        }
}
```

I tried to execute this in remix to gather a better understanding, but it raised a bunch of errors I didn't knew how to fix. **So I would like to understand how can contract A find contract B to call the `g` method if the address of contract B isn't stored? Same with contract B finding A to call method `f`.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work because as you said A and B addresses are not stored in B and A.

The exemple you linked his about compilation and importing, and cannot works in test (infinite loop and no setup for `a` and `b` values). Something like that should do the trick for the setup but be aware that the infinite loop is still present

```
contract InterfaceOfA {
        function f(uint) returns (uint);
}

contract InterfaceOfB {
        function g(bool) returns (bool);
}

contract A is InterfaceOfA {
        InterfaceOfB b;
        function f(uint _input) returns (uint) {
                b.g(true);
                return 3;
        }

        function setB(address bAddress) {
                b = InterfaceOfB(bAddress);
        }
}

contract B is InterfaceOfB {
        InterfaceOfA a;
        function g(bool _input) returns (bool) {
                a.f(0);
                return false;
        }

        function setA(address aAddress) {
                a = InterfaceOfA(aAddress);
        }
}
```